# how to make factor of this expression

Tags: factoring, unique-factorization-domains

How do I factor $x^4 + x^2 y^2 + y^4$? And in how many ways can I make the factor?

Some methods I know are

1. Mid term Break
2. Substiturion Method
3. Quadratic Equation

Comment: This thing has a nice graph, between a circle and a square for, say, $$ x^4 + x^2  y^2 + y^4 = 3,    $$ so you get easy points at $(\pm 1, \pm 1),$ and four points on the axes at $\sqrt {\sqrt 3} \approx 1.316$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $x^4 + x^2 y^2 + y^4 = (x^4 + 2 x^2 y^2 + y^4) - x^2 y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x^4+x^2+1=\left( {x}^{2}+x+1 \right)  \left( {x}^{2}-x+1 \right) $